# Passive Subjunctive Translated as Active

Tags: conjunctive, passive-voice, indirect-question, voice

Moreland has this line:

> Cognoscebamus quo tempore dux mortem illis patriam neglegentibus minatus esset

This is an indirect question, hence the sequence of tenses: main verb takes Imperfect; secondary verb takes pluperfect.

*Minatus esset* is obviously Pluperfect **Passive** Subjunctive yet the translation I found at utoronoto's website was:

> We learned when the leader had threatened death to those neglecting the
>   fatherland.

But why is the passive *minatus esset* being translated as active? I tried taking the *illis neglegentibus* as Ablative of Cause instead of Dative and translated it (wrongly, because dux is nominative) as:

> We learned at what time leader death **by those** neglecting the fatherland had been threatened.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 7):

The verb in question ([*minor, -ari, -atus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dminor1)) is a [**deponent verb**](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.190.html), which means that it has a passive form but an active meaning.

There are *many* such verbs in Latin. Consider the following cases:

> *Multa passus est.*
>
> He suffered many things.

or:

> *Te hortamur...*
>
> We urge you...